# Divide a circle horizontally

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

I'm in the midst of programming, and I'd like to know if this is possible.

*Given a circle which we know three facts:*

1. *The center point;*
2. *The radius; and*
3. *The Y coordinate of a line parallel to the X axis,*

*find the two X coordinates where the circle crosses said line.*

I've attempted to mess about with the circle's equation,

## $(x-h)²+(y-k)²=r²$

with the Circle center being $(h,k)$ and the radius $r$.

In short, I'm dividing a circle horizontally.

My attempts to get a functional formula (e.g. $x=fancyPants$) seem to be failing. I cannot math good.

Is this possible or am I unwittingly jumping into ridiculously complex math that will blow up the program with trial and error?

If possible, I would like a formula for an ellipsis as well.

Cheers

Comment: You have the right info: the radius and the $y$ coordinate are two sides of a right triangle.  Figuring out what the third side represents is the important piece (hint: the $x$ coordinate...)

Comment: An ellipse will in this case be almost identical in how to arrive at the solution...

Comment: Simply put that ordinate in the equation, and solve for $x$, answers will be desired abscissa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the circle's center have coordinates $(h, k)$ and radius $r$.  Then the points with $y$-coordinate $y_0$ (if there are any) have $x$-coordinates that satisfy the equation

$$
(x-h)^2 + (y_0-k)^2 = r^2
$$

The only unknown here is $x$, so we write

$$
(x-h)^2 = r^2-(y_0-k)^2
$$

and then

$$
x-h = \pm \sqrt{r^2-(y_0-k)^2}
$$

Finally, we add $h$ to both sides to get

$$
x = h \pm \sqrt{r^2-(y_0-k)^2}
$$

This will yield two (real) solutions when $r > |y_0-k|$, one solution when $r = |y_0-k|$, and no (real) solutions when $r < |y_0-k|$, where $|z|$ is the absolute value of $z$.

Pseudocode is

```
if (r < fabs(y0-k))
    return {NaN};
else if (r == fabs(y_0-k))
    return {h};
else {
    d = sqrt(r^2-(y0-k)^2);
    return {h-d, h+d};
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. My 'helpful' comments from family members ended up in removing all squaring entirely, and never mind the loss of ±.
Is an ellipse the same formula?

Comment: If the ellipse is aligned either vertically or horizontally, then the same approach can be used with minor modifications.  We write the ellipse's formula as $(x-h)^2/a^2+(y-k)^2/b^2 = 1$.  Set $y = y_0$ and bring the $y$ term over to the right side: $(x-h)^2/a^2 = 1-(y_0-k)^2/b^2$.  Multiply both sides by $a^2$ to get $(x-h)^2 = a^2-(y_0-k)^2a^2/b^2$.  Take the square root of both sides to obtain $x-h = \pm a\sqrt{1-(y_0-k)^2/b^2}$, and then finally $x = h \pm a\sqrt{1-(y_0-k)^2/b^2}$.  The number of roots again depends on the argument of the square root.